# extjs pagingtoolbar refresh

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4, store, paging

I have a grid with local **memory** store. I can list the **records in pages** using **pagingtoolbar**. However, **after filtering** the data, I load filtered records to a new store and bind this store to the same pagingtoolbar. Then **pagingtoolbar** becomes **disabled**. In this state, when I check the **pagingtoolbar**'s data it **shows the correct values** (total records and pages etc.). But the toolbar is disabled.

How can I update the view of paging toolbar?

Here some code:

```
var newStore = Ext.create('APP.myLocalStore', {
                data: filteredStore.data,
                totalCount: filteredStore.count()
            });
pagingToolbar.bindStore();
pagingToolbar.bindStore(newStore);
pagingToolbar.moveFirst();
```

I am using extjs 4.x

Comment: I solved my problem, there was another issue with store. Also pagingtoolbar.onLoad() function does the refresh but I think it is not pretty.

Answer (score 1):

You can use pagination bar refresh also. Try

Ext.getCmp('pagination bar').doRefresh()